# How to convert YAMAHA digital mixing console fader value to MIDI

Tags: midi

I'd like to convert YAMAHA digital mixing console "fader value"(db) to MIDI data.

I understand that yamaha mixing console use two "MIDI control change message"(fader L, fader H) to expressed each fader in high resolution.

However, I don't understand how to "fader value"(db) mapping those message.
I captured that message, but did't find out that rules.

Is there calculatin method or mapping table ?

Please could you help me.

### Capture Data: ch 1 fader

```
0.0db
RECEIVE    | ENDPOINT(AUDIO4c DIN) TYPE(CONTROLCHANGE) CHANNEL(1) DATA1(1) DATA2(102)
RECEIVE    | ENDPOINT(AUDIO4c DIN) TYPE(CONTROLCHANGE) CHANNEL(1) DATA1(33) DATA2(119)

0.15db
RECEIVE    | ENDPOINT(AUDIO4c DIN) TYPE(CONTROLCHANGE) CHANNEL(1) DATA1(1) DATA2(103)
RECEIVE    | ENDPOINT(AUDIO4c DIN) TYPE(CONTROLCHANGE) CHANNEL(1) DATA1(33) DATA2(39)

0.45
RECEIVE    | ENDPOINT(AUDIO4c DIN) TYPE(CONTROLCHANGE) CHANNEL(1) DATA1(1) DATA2(104)
RECEIVE    | ENDPOINT(AUDIO4c DIN) TYPE(CONTROLCHANGE) CHANNEL(1) DATA1(33) DATA2(7)
```

- That Console setting is default:

  - Control change number 1 to "fader H Input CH 1"
  - Control change number 33 to "fader L Input CH 1"
  - Mode: SINGLE / TABLE
- Console: YAMAHA QL5
- Capture Application: Protokol(https://hexler.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 14-bit controller (see p. 17 of the [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/midi1-specifications/m1-v4-2-1-midi-1-0-detailed-specification-96-1-4)); the actual controller value is MSB*128+LSB.

So the mapping is as follows:
0.00 -> 13175
0.15 -> 13223
0.45 -> 13319

This is perfectly linear. So CC = 13175 + 320 * dB, and dB = (CC - 13175) / 320.

Comment: Thanks you!
I didn't thinking that actual controller value.
That's right. The values; 13175 -> 13223 -> ... is perfectly linear.
I understand the law, and I can convert YAMAHA mixing console fader value <-> MIDI value.